# Extracting flat areas and saving them as lakes using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, srtm, watershed, lakes

I would like to extract lakes and sea from a DEM (SRTM) and save them as a separate layer.

Is this possible?

I have tried to extract flat areas with the Raster Calculator, but that did not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to extract the slope first from the DEM using the `Raster -> Terrain Analysis -> Slope` OR `Raster -> Analysis -> DEM (Terrain Models)`. Then use the slope raster to extract the lakes or sea where the `slope = 0`

Using `Raster Calculator`, it will be like this:

```
"Slope@1" = 0
```

Where `"Slope@1"` is the raster name. So The general form is `"RasterName@1" = 0`

Here is the input:

[image]

Here is the output after applying the above expression:

[image]

The green color is the lakes extracted from the slope raster.

Comment: the additional step would be vectorisation of of the raster so you get the lakes as a vector layer

Comment: @LaughU Thanks for your input. I forgot to mention this in my answer.

Comment: This might give you false results, since there are also flat areas (slope=0) that are not lakes or water

Comment: @Miron Are you down voting because there are other areas that could be flat without being lake or sea. This is true, but if you have better automatic solution with zero error I am glad to see it. The OP can easily filter lakes/sea by different ways, which is out of this scope.